# Generate the number for Sunday by finding the pattern

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

I found this puzzle on another site so I put it here to share with you.
I will give link for the pattern logic of given puzzle.

[image]

Answer:
   [Click here](http://www.puzzles-world.com/2017/01/monday-617-tuesday-729-sunday.html)

Comment: Please source the other site

Comment: Aww, why the unaccept? (I'm not really complaining - perfectly happy for MCN to get the tick instead, and I've upvoted their answer - just wondering.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is

> 6713

As,

> first digit(6) is for number of lettes in 'Sunday', 7 is for continuing sequence and 13 is for number of letters + sequence starting with 1 (from Monday onwards)

Answer (score 26):

The answer is

> 6713

because

> the first digit is the number of letters in the word "Sunday", the second digit is the position of Sunday in the week (starting from Monday), and the other digits are the sum of the first two.

This same pattern worked to generate all the other numbers for Monday to Saturday - check it!

Answer (score 9):

It is

> 606

Because

> The first digit is the number of letters in the day. The second digit is 0 because you start counting the days of the week with Sunday, not Monday, and you start counting at zero. The last digit is the sum of the first two.

Comment: Ideally it should be _0606_ as there are **four** question marks(?) are provided against Sunday to be filled! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you count Sunday as the start of the week or not.

If you do its 0606

If not then its 6713